# Delete re-entry of a word in a new line after a a table

Tags: tables, indentation

Goodmorning,

In my code I want that the new line after a table start with the same margins of the other part of the text without any re-entry. To be more cleare this is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{times}
\providecommand{\keywords}[1]{\textbf{\textit{Keywords:}} #1}
\providecommand{\jel}[1]{\textbf{\textit{JEL Classification:}} #1}

\def\permille{\ensuremath{{}^\text{o}\mkern-5mu/\mkern-3mu_\text{oo}}}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\footremember}[2]{%
    \footnote{#2}
    \newcounter{#1}
    \setcounter{#1}{\value{footnote}}%
}
\newcommand{\footrecall}[1]{%
    \footnotemark[\value{#1}]%
} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol} % used for the two-column index
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\floatsetup[figure]{capposition=top}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  useprefix,
  backend=biber,
  isbn = false,
  doi = false,
  language=auto,
  style=apa,
  sorting=nyt,
  uniquename=false,
  natbib]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliosim.bib}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrr}
\multicolumn{8}{c}{Coefficient of Variation}\\
\hline
& Min. & Q1 & Median & Mean & Q3 & Max. \\
\hline
 Direct & 7.81 & 12.23 & 16.03 & 18.93 & 22.62 & 74.22 \\ 
 GAMLSS & 3.32 & 6.86 & 8.03 & 8.97 &9.56 & 27.10 \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Summary of coefficient of variation}
\label{result}
\end{table}
To obtain reliable estimates \dots 

\end{document}
```

In this way I obtain the table but the next line of code ("to obtain etc..) start with a re-entry, as done after an equation if I left one line of code empity.

How can I delete this re-entry?

Thanks you!

Comment: note that the point of `table` environment is a float that is not part of the document flow so "To ob.." is the start of the document. You could use `\noindent` but logically better would be to use `tabular` not in `table` so it starts the paragraph

Comment: urelated but `\newcounter{#1}` should not be inside the macro you do not want to allocate a new counter each time